# how to link a prismaschema with type like "user.type.ts"?

Tags: typescript, prisma

i've some problems on my creation with 2 table, when i want to create a client, i wish i could link a bill to it, but when i try to link it with with my type, she doesn't want to..
i've this probleme from an other table, these link i've tried to fix is two "one-to-many" link

```
model CompactThirds {
  idThirdCompact Int @id @default(autoincrement())
//
  shipping Shipping[]
  invoices Invoice[]
}
```

the compactthirds model link for exemple with :

```
model Shipment{
  idNumBl Int @id @default(autoincrement())
//
  // Relations
  treatmentId Treatment[]
  ThirdCompact ThirdCompact? @relation(fields: [tiersCompacteId], references: [idTiersCompacte],      onDelete: SetNull, onUpdate: Cascade)
  thirdCompacteId Int?
}
```

and my type are :

```
export type CompactThirds = {
  name: string;
  address: string;
//
  shipment: number;
  invoices: number;
};
```

the create only working without these number of shipment & invoices, i tried to do something like

```
export type CompactThirds = {
  name: string;
  address: string;
//
  shipment: Shipment;
  invoices: Invoices;
};
```

but its not working too..

Maybe i can have some help figure it out ?
Many thanks !

Comment: Prisma generates the types for you... not sure what you want here.

Comment: "but its not working" What isn't working? Do you get an type error? Do you get a runtime error? If so what does that error say?

Comment: src/services/tierCompacte.services.ts(29,73): error TS2322: Type 'CreateTiersCompacte' is not assignable to type '(Without<TiersCompacteCreateInput, TiersCompacteUncheckedCreateInput> & TiersCompacteUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & TiersCompacteCreateInput)'.
 Type 'CreateTiersCompacte' is not assignable to type 'Without<TiersCompacteUncheckedCreateInput, TiersCompacteCreateInput> & TiersCompacteCreateInput'.
Types of property 'expedition' are incompatible.
Type 'number' has no properties in common with type 'ExpeditionCreateNestedManyWithoutTiersCompacteInput'.

Comment: that's what the server said to me...

Comment: Can you share the query that you are invoking?